# MySQL Laravel query optimization

Tags: mysql, laravel, optimization

I've a query which I need to optimize to gain load speed.

```
select `wp`.`version` as `wp_version`, count(*) as total from `site_products` as `sp` 
  inner join `wp_versions` as `wp` on `sp`.`site_id` = `wp`.`site_id` 
    where `sp`.`product_id` = 3 and `wp`.`updated_at` between '2023-10-22 00:00:00' and '2023-11-22 23:59:59' 
    group by `wp`.`version` order by `total` desc
```

in Laravel its:

```
    $data['wp_vers'] = DB::table('site_products AS sp')
                         ->join('wp_versions as wp', 'sp.site_id', '=', 'wp.site_id')
        ->select(
            'wp.version as wp_version',
            DB::raw('count(*) as total')
        )
        ->where('sp.product_id', '=', $product_id)
        ->whereBetween('wp.updated_at', [$dates['start'].' 00:00:00', $dates['end']. ' 23:59:59'])
        ->groupBy('wp.version')
        ->orderBy('total','desc')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

I've already optimized it to use wp_versions table instead of heavier site_meta table. But needs further optimization.

Comment: What indexes are you using? Also try doing date concatenation before the query

Comment: if you can show an explain of that query, that would help tremendously